# Powershell: Comparing a value between two arrays, and extracting a related value

Tags: arrays, powershell, csv

so here is what I'm trying to accomplish.

I have a form for a new starter, New Starter Form.csv, that has the following headers and information:

> firstname,lastname,teamname,startdate
>
> Joe,Bloggs,Security Admin,01/01/18

I have a different csv called Team List.csv, that has the following headers and information:

> teamlead,teamname,resgroup
>
> A B,Marketing,RESMARKETING01G
>
> C D,Product,RESPRODUCT01G
>
> E F,Advertising,RESADVERTISING01G
>
> G H,Security Admin,RESSECURITYADMIN01G

I want to import both CSV files into Powershell, run a comparisson that takes the team name from the New Starter Form, and checks if there are any matches in the Team List, and if so, add the relevant RES group to the new starter in AD.

Currently, I can import them, compare them, find a match, and find an index number for the record, but I'm struggling to the take this index number, and use it to get the relevant RES group. So far the code looks like this:

```
$teamlist = import-csv "\\location\Team List.csv"
$newstarter = import-csv "\\otherlocation\New Starter Form.csv"
    
[string]$teamname = Compare-Object -includeequal -excludedifferent -PassThru $newstarter.teamname $teamlist.teamname 
    
$teamname

[array]::indexof($teamlist,$teamname)
```

And running that, provides us with this in the console, showing that we can indeed see the match, and that the matching record is the last (-1) one:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $teamlist = import-csv "\\location\Team List.csv"
$newstarter = import-csv "\\otherlocation\New Starter Form.csv"

[string]$teamname = Compare-Object -includeequal -excludedifferent -PassThru $newstarter.teamname $teamlist.teamname 

$teamname

[array]::indexof($teamlist,$teamname)

Security Administration
-1
```

I've not got a lot of experience with Powershell, and my coding knowledge is pretty limited overall, but I'm used to the concept that I can save the index value as a variable, and then I could call that variable back to do something like `$teamlist.resgroup[VARIABLE HERE]`.
But if I try and declare a new variable before `[array]::indexof($teamlist,$teamname)`, Powershell isn't happy.

Whilst I've not looked into it, I believe a possible alternative could be to add in a huge switch statement, but I may be looking at having 100+ teams overall, and I'd like to avoid inefficient code wherever I can. Am I missing something obvious though? Is there a better way (Or even just a functioning way would be great!) that this could work?

Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$teamlist = import-csv "\\location\Team List.csv"
$newstarter = import-csv "\\otherlocation\New Starter Form.csv"

 # get a single new starter
$person = $newstarter | Where-Object { $_.firstname -eq 'Joe' -and $_.lastname -eq 'Bloggs' }

# get the new starters team
$team = $teamlist | Where-Object { $_.teamname -eq $person.teamname }

# get the new starters resource group
$resgroup = $team.resgroup

# use the resource group - this simply writes it to the console
Write-Host $resgroup
```

The code above will:

- import your two csvs
- grab a single new starter from your new starter csv, based on first &
  last name
- grab the team & resource group for that new starter from the team list
- display the resgroup (this is where you will need to use to populate AD)

Comment: That's far simpler, and works like a charm, thanks a lot!

Comment: No problem. Glad to help :)